# Why does the last character double when I erase other characters, and how do I prevent it?

Tags: c++, stl

I've got following code:

```
auto rrr="my mixed string"s;
rrr.erase(std::remove_if(std::begin(rrr), std::end(rrr), [](char const c) { return c == 'm'; }));
std::cout<<rrr<<std::endl;
```

The output is `y ixed stringg`

I expected for the code to just remove every `m` in the string, instead it also added a `g` at the end

Why did this happen, and how do I fix this?

Comment: `rrr.erase(std::remove_if(std::begin(rrr), std::end(rrr), [](char const c) { return c == 'm'; }), std::end(rrr));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the wrong `erase()` overload. You're calling the `erase()` overload that takes a single iterator parameter, an iterator to the single character to be removed from the string.

`std::remove_if` "removes" the values from the sequence by simply moving them to the end, and then returns a new "sequence ending" iterator value. Your call to the wrong `erase()` overload removes only the character after the new sequence. If nothing was removed, you would have passed `end()` to `erase()` resulting in undefined behavior and a likely crash. But in this case, you got off lucky.

To completely erase the "removed" characters that were moved to the end of the string, pass the string's `end()` iterator to `erase()` as well:

```
rrr.erase( /* What you already have */, rrr.end());
```

Your C++ book, or C++ reference manual, should have a complete list of all available overloads of `erase()`, including the one that you should've used here, and an explanation on what they do.

Comment: `by simply moving them to the end` Technically, remove does sort of the opposite: It moves the not-removed elements from the end, over the removed ones. The elements that stay in the back are in a moved-from state (which for trivial type means they are copies of the original). But this is just *semantics* :)

Answer (score 1):

Or use boost version (if boost is available for you), avoiding all bloaty code.

```
boost::range::remove_erase_if(rrr, [](char c) { return c == 'm'; });
```